# Use Data index to print all items in a row in a Python List

Tags: python

I have a Python List and I have implemented a click listener for the items in, if i have the index of an item in that list,

E.g, I can get the text ( 'text': '0000' ), where index = 3 or the text ('text': '100') where index = 24,
how can use an index of the item to print all the other data in row in which that index lies?

```
data = [{'text': '400'}, {'text': 'Dairy'}, {'text': '0000'}, {'text': 'Milkshake'}, {'text': '500'}, {'text': 'Available'}, {'text': '0.0'}, {'text': '1'}, {'text': 'Kisumu'}, 

{'text': '500'}, {'text': 'Electronics'}, {'text': '1111'}, {'text': 'Flower'}, {'text': '700'}, {'text': 'Available'}, {'text': '50'}, {'text': '2'}, {'text': 'Kisumu'},

{'text': '500'}, {'text': 'Electronics'}, {'text': '8888'}, {'text': 'Eggs'}, {'text': '900'}, {'text': 'Unavailable'}, {'text': '100'}, {'text': '5'}, {'text': 'Kisumu'}]
```

Diagramatic Data
[image: Diagramatic data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_row_range(index:int, num_cols:int) -> range:
    # index - index, which you want the row of
    # num_cols - number of columns in your table
    row = int(index/num_cols) # the row you want
    return range(row * num_cols, (row+1)*num_cols) # the range which that index lies

# Example usage of querying the index '10'
clicked_index = 10 # in the event handler get which index was clicked
num_cols = 9 # your example has 9 columns
for i in get_row_range(clicked_index, num_cols):
    print(data[i]["text"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way...

```
data = [{'text': '400'}, {'text': 'Dairy'}, {'text': '0000'}, {'text': 'Milkshake'}, {'text': '500'}, {'text': 'Available'}, {'text': '0.0'}, {'text': '1'}, {'text': 'Kisumu'}, 
        {'text': '500'}, {'text': 'Electronics'}, {'text': '1111'}, {'text': 'Flower'}, {'text': '700'}, {'text': 'Available'}, {'text': '50'}, {'text': '2'}, {'text': 'Kisumu'},
        {'text': '500'}, {'text': 'Electronics'}, {'text': '8888'}, {'text': 'Eggs'}, {'text': '900'}, {'text': 'Unavailable'}, {'text': '100'}, {'text': '5'}, {'text': 'Kisumu'}]

rows = [data[x:x+9] for x in range(0,len(data),9)]  # split to rows

idx = 24

print(rows[idx//9])
```

Output

```
[{'text': '500'}, {'text': 'Electronics'}, {'text': '8888'}, {'text': 'Eggs'}, {'text': '900'}, {'text': 'Unavailable'}, {'text': '100'}, {'text': '5'}, {'text': 'Kisumu'}]
```